# How to detect a class and get li number using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get li number by detect a class.

Example :

```
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="current"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
<div class="value"></div>
```

I want the `class="current"` `<li>` number.

```
$('.value').text(//need class="current" li number);
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by **"number"** - as it stands, it could be 1. The count (1 in the example), 2. The index (3rd), 3: The value inside (3).

Comment: Please see update......

Comment: Last update does not explain expected results. This whole problem description is completely lacking in proper details. Elements don't have `numbers` and if you want information from them you need to explain exactly what that is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index() is what you're looking for I think

```
$('.current').index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not entirely clear so I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for the "index" or the "actual text".

For learning purposes, here are the steps:
1) use a `.<classname>` to specify the class you want to look for
2) use `index()` or `html()` or `text()` to get the info you need

Additional info/explanation of each usage can be found here:

https://api.jquery.com/index/
`$('.current').index()`

http://api.jquery.com/html/
`$('.current').html()`

http://api.jquery.com/text/
`$('.current').text()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update, it seems like you want the index, correct? This is how you would accomplish this:

```
$('.value').text($("li.current").index()); //2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `class` is find by getting children of `ul` and finding whether element has class or not. If class is available then print `class name` and `element value`

`.attr('class')` return class name if available else return  `undefined`

```js
$('ul').children().each(function(index, el) {
  if ($(this).attr('class')) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    alert($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="current">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```